# Windows pptp VPN at startup

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, startup, pptp, pptp-client

I'd like to connect windows pptp client at startup.

Is it possible?

because I need a vpn link between two windows server and so (because it's a server) I don't want to let a logged user to the system....

Even if you have a comment on what I want to achieve don't hesitate to tell me.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/737799/how-to-connect-to-a-vpn-on-start-up This should work for you if you want to connect without logging in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to do that!

I'm not expert in networking. I'm a developer so I always take time to achieve what I want to do :s

So the solution is : to use the "Routing and Remote Access" role of windows server to establish a router-to-router vpn link.

You can find more information on the msdn here : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787527%28WS.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you need to connect to a Virtual Private Network at windows startup, and you don't want to have the user push connect or enter the password do the following:

1. On the VPN Connect screen, check "Save this user name and password for the following users"
2. Select the "Anyone who uses this computer" radio button
3. Click "Properties" on the VPN Connect screen
4. On the "Options" tab, uncheck:

   - "Display progress while connecting"
   - "Prompt for name and password, certificate,etc."
5. In Windows Explorer, browse to C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
6. Open a new Windows Explorer and browse to Control Panel\Network Connections
7. Drag the icon of your VPN connection to the Startup folder. This will create a shortcut

Now at Windows startup, the [VPN service](http://vpnprivacy.com) will launch and connect silently.

Comment: yes but it connect only after you login. But I have a windows server and I need VPN to be connect all the time.